# Como quebrar página usando o mPDF

Tags: php, pdf

Gostaria de fazer uma quebra de página a cada documento gerado. Consultei a documentação mas não entendi.

O que tenho é isso aqui:

```
$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean(); // Finaliza o fluxo

include("../../MPDF57/mpdf.php");
 
// cria um novo container PDF no formato A4 com orientação customizada
$mpdf=new mPDF('pt','A4',3,'',8,8,5,14,9,9,'P');
 
// muda o charset para aceitar caracteres acentuados iso 8859-1 utilizados por mim no banco de dados e na geracao do conteudo PHP com HTML
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='iso-8859-1';
 
//Algumas configurações do PDF
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// modo de visualização
$rodape = '{DATE j/m/Y H:i}|{PAGENO}/{nb}| Gerado automaticamente pelo Sistema';
$mpdf->SetFooter($rodape);
//bacana este rodape, nao eh mesmo?
 
// carrega uma folha de estilo - MAGICA!!!
$stylesheet1 = file_get_contents('../../css/stgeral.css');
$stylesheet2 = file_get_contents('../../bootcocari/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$stylesheet3 = file_get_contents('../../bootcocari/css/bootstrap.icon-large.css');
$stylesheet4 = file_get_contents('../css/styleCurriculo.css');
 
// incorpora a folha de estilo ao PDF
// O parâmetro 1 diz que este é um css/style e deverá ser interpretado como tal
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet1,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet2,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet3,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet4,1);
 
// incorpora o corpo ao PDF na posição 2 e deverá ser interpretado como footage. Todo footage é posicao 2 ou 0(padrão).
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
 
// define um nome para o arquivo PDF
$arquivo = date("dmy_"). '_curriculos.pdf';
 
// gera o relatório
$mpdf->Output($arquivo,'I');
 
exit();
```

Comment: Olá Você quer forçar uma segunda página?

Comment: Olá @RafaelMenaBarreto, sim, por exemplo, gero 10 páginas e gostaria de poder quebrar página a cada uma que é gerada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na biblioteca `mpdf` o método para criar uma nova página é o `addPage`. Este método pode ser utilizado toda vez que você quiser criar uma página de maneira forçada, ou seja, quando você quer que a nova página seja iniciada independentemente do espaço livre na página anterior.

```
$mpdf->AddPage();
```

Todo o `$mpdf->writeHtml()` que você mandar depois disso vai para a página nova. Se você tem 10 páginas vai ter que usar o método 10 vezes ou através de um `foreach`.

Comment: Em que posição utilizo esse comando, no final do código?

Comment: Toda vez que você precisar criar uma página nova.

Comment: Bom dia, @RafaelMenaBarreto. Eu tenho um relatório que vai ser impresso 25 linhas por página. Digamos que eu tenha 300 páginas para imprimir. Como eu faria isso. Não seria melhor usar um for ao invés do foreach?Você teria como exemplificar de uma forma mais clara, pfv.

Answer (score 0):

Para força a quebra de página basta adicionar `$html .= '<pagebreak />';` após o item que deseja jogar em outra página.

Se estiver usando laço de repetição como por exemplo `while`, basta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
while:

  <tabe></table>

  $html .= '<pagebreak />';

endwhile;
```